# How to get reference to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am getting this error when i try to use the rtdb on an angularfire2 app.

```
ERROR TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.database is not a function
    at new AuthService (auth.service.ts:29)
    at _createClass (core.js:9272)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:9234)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:9200)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:9911)
    at resolveDep (core.js:10276)
    at createClass (core.js:10152)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:10033)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:11255)
    at callViewAction (core.js:11571)
```

I imported firebase as follows:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

The following gives me the above error:

```
db = firebase.database();
```

Comment: Do you also need to `import 'firebase/database'`?

Comment: I tried that but, it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Import it like this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

Answer (score 0):

use [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2https://github.com/angular/angularfire2), It can be insalled by npm